# C++ library for Ethereum client documentation

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I am looking for documentation for C++ Eth client. So it will be really helpful if you could share few useful links to understand how Eth client command works.

Answer (score 4):

From the main [Ethereum GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum) page, you want the [`cpp-ethereum`](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum) repository (right in the middle of the main page).

The `README` for the repository contains lots of useful links, including to the main `cpp-ethereum` [documentation](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/).

Comment: Cannot find all the Eth command line parameter related examples while going through this link. If you share the same will be helpful.